# How to suppress ListedColormap object location displayed on plot?

Tags: matplotlib

I wrote a function to plot rows of digits that correspond to the conformations of single amino acids in a polypeptide taken from a molecular dynamics simulation. Here is the code:

```
def plot_matrix_wt(matrix, title='KTPP Conformations'):
    cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['k','y','b','g','r','c']); 
    rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 5
    plt.imshow(matrix,cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks=[0.4, 1.25, 2.1, 2.95, 3.75, 4.6],label=cmap)
    cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['None', 'Beta', 'PPII', 'Alpha', 'L-Alpha', 'Alpha_Turn']) 
    plt.xticks([5,15,25,35],('K','T','P','P'));
    plt.ylabel('Proportion of Simulation Frames [%]')
    plt.show()
```

[function output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5pyy.png)

The problem is that I get the object location of the ListedColormap displayed alongside the colorbar on my plot. Is there any way to suppress it? Ive used %matplotlib inline and ; after defining the cmap as suggested in other responses to similar questions but nothing has worked yet. Thanks very much

Comment: You set the colorbar label yourself to this. Use `label="My text here"` to display a different text.

Comment: When I click on the image "function output" on my post it shows up with a black background so the output Id like to suppress doesnt show up (the text is black). To clarify- veritcally oriented alongside the colorbar I get this: <matplotlib.colors.ListedColorMap object at 0x11138160>

Comment: I just removed "label = cmap" from plt.colorbar(..) and the undesirable output disappeared. Problem solved. Thanks very much all